# Finding a generator of GF(16)*

Tags: field-theory

I have to find a generator of the multiplicative group $GF(16)$. Where $GF(p)$ denotes a finit field with $p$ elements.

The problem here is, that 16 isn't prime.

I'm gonna solve it and just write all my questions when they appear.

Solution:

We know that $GF(16)^*$ denotes a field with 16 elements. Since 16 isn't prime, we have a problem, since we have zero-dividers in $GF(16)$. [e.g. 8+8 mod 16 = 0] So we need more elements.

I think the basic idea here is to switch to another field which is isomorphic to get more elements. [That's very unclear though].

We first note that the order of $GF(16)*$ is $\varphi(16)=2³=8$ We also know, that the order of any subgroup divides the order of the group, so:

$ord(a)\in \{1,2,4,8\} \ \ \forall a\in GF(16)*$

So we are looking for $a$ which fullfil $a^2\neq 1, a^4\neq 1$ or $a^8=1$. Since $a^2=a^4$ if $a^2=1$ we can just check for $a^4\neq 1$ to find a generator.

Now, the question is, what are our a's?

Because we have $16=2^4$ we can switch to $GF(2)[x]$ and look for a irreducible polynomial of order 4. I see why we need a irreducible polynomial (otherwise we don't have a field) but I don't exactly see why we can switch to $GF(2)$ and why we need a polynomial of degree 4.

Anyway, let's go ahead. So we are looking for a irreducible polynomial of degree 4. Let's take $x^4 + x^3 + 1=m(x)$. I found it by just trying it out, guess that's the only thing one can do.

So we are now looking for a generator for $GF(2)[x]_{x^4+x^3+1}$

We know that we need a polynomial $a(x)$ which fullwills $a(x)^4\not\equiv_{m(x)} 1$

Again, no idea how to do that other than just trying it out. Anyway, we would, by just trying it out, find such an $a(x)$ which then would be our generator.

So, my questions are:

Question 1: Why can we switch from $GF(16)$ to $GF(2)[x]_{m(x)}$.
Question 2. How can we systematically and easily find $m(x)$
Question 3: How can we systematically and easily find $a(x)$?

Comment: From the beginning, I think you're confusing the field $\;\Bbb F_{2^4}=GF(2^4)\;$ , which of course **cannot have non-zero zero divisors, with the non-integer domain $\;\Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z_{16}\;$, which not only has many non-zero divisors but in fact also nilpotent ones.

Comment: You are also mixing notations and definitions: when $\;\Bbb F\;$ is *any* field, we usually denote by $\;\Bbb F^*\;$ the multiplicative **group** of non-zero elements. Thus, the number of elements in $\;GF(16)^*\;$ is $\;15\;$ . That you use for this the Euler Totient function points, once again, towards a fundamental confusion between the field with $\;16\;$ elements and **the ring** $\;\Bbb Z_{16}\;$. Check your notes.

Comment: You are right,  $GF(16)^*$ has indeed only 15 elements. I don't get your first comment though. I don't know what $\mathbb F_{2^4}$ should be nor do I know the notation $GF(2^4)$. Also I have no idea what $\mathbb / 16\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z_{16}$ denotes.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I won't be able to help you, as you don't know the basics I think you should to understand my comments and my answer below. This question is usually asked in a course in Fields Theory, Galois Theory or something like that, and I think one must already know some pretty basic and important facts in group and ring theory...

Comment: $GF(16)$ is ***not*** "arithmetic modulo 16".

Comment: @DonAntonio I meant that I don't know your Notation. Different courses might use different notation and thus denote stuff differently.

Comment: @Hurkyl GF(16) is just our notation for a finit field with 16 elements.

Comment: Ah I might have a typo up there. Gonna recheck it later - on a hurry right now.

Comment: @xotix: Right. Arithmetic modulo 16 is not a field. $GF(16)$ is not isomorphic to the ring of integers modulo 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take any irreducible quartic in $\;\Bbb F_2[x]\;$ , say $\;p(x)=x^4+x+1\;$ . Then in fact

$$GF(16)=\Bbb F_{2^4}\cong \Bbb F_2[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$$

and thus we can denote every element in $\;\Bbb F_{16}\;$ as a polynomial of degree *at most three* in $\;w\;$, where $\;w\;$ is any root of $\;p(x)\;$ . For example, we could take $\;w=x+\langle p(x)\rangle \in \Bbb F_2[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle\;$ . Of course, **all the operations carried on** in these algebraic structures are done $\;\pmod 2\;$ .

For example, with the above $\;w\;$:

$$w^5=w(w^4)=w(w+1)=w^2+w\neq1\,,\;\;w^3\neq1$$

...and we're done, since the order of $\;w\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_{16}^*\;$ must be a divisor of $\;\left|\Bbb F_{16}^*\right|=15\;$ ,and it isn't $\;3\;$ or $\;5\;$ (and obviously it isn't $\;1\;$ , either) , thus it **must** be $\;15\;$ , so $\;\Bbb F_{16}^*=\langle w\rangle\;$

Comment: Thanks, going to look into it today.